# Как сделать обновление (pull) в удаленном репозитории после команды push

Tags: git, gitlab

Есть репозиторий в Gitlab. Репозиторий клонирован на другом сервере.

Необходим сделать так, чтобы после push в репозиторий проекта в Gitlab, удаленный репозиторий выполнил команду pull.

**Update**:

На сервере nginx в настройках указал locations, в котором с помощью lua вызывается баш скрипт с обновлением репозитория и настроил webhook в Gitlab на этот url.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать hooks. Внутри хука можно по ssh или другим способом дергнуть "другой сервер" и он все сделает.

Comment: @KoVadim, кстати, а что такое hooks в данном случае?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html

но думаю, Вам больше понравятся webhooks https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/web_hooks/web_hooks.html

Comment: @KoVadim не подскажите, как правильно webhooks использовать? Я так понимаю надо скрипт написать на сервере где лежит удаленный репозиторий и добавить ссылку на него в Gitlab.

Comment: Вначале на "другом сервере" нужно написать скрипт, который будет делать нужное действие (пулить, к примеру). Потом зайти в гитлаб в вебхуки и на хук пуша добавить "дергание скрипта". Но самое главное, пулл может быть не быстрым делом. А гитлаб рассчитывает, что все отработает быстро. Поэтому, запускайте задачу в бекграунд и сразу отвечайте гитлабу, что все ок.

Answer (score -1):

А вам критично, чтобы это происходило сразу же? В большинстве случаев достаточно настроить расписание на pull три раза в день - утром, в обед и вечером.